# How to open a link in new tab in JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON code, and I want to know how to make the links open in new browser tabs.  I know that in HTML you use `target="_blank"`, but what do I do in JSON file?  I know nothing about JSON.  Here is the code I got from a plugin:

```js
var tipuesearch = {"pages": [
     {"title": "My title", "text": "Description of my title", "tags": "tag1, tag2", "loc": "http://www.example.com/"}
]};
```

What do I need to add in the file to open the `"loc"` in a new browser tap?

Or do I need to do this in a different file?  The Javascript functions are in the following link (in case you need it, but it is a long file): https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Site-Search-Engine-Plugin-Tipue-Search/demos/static/tipuesearch/tipuesearch.js

Comment: That's JavaScript, not JSON.

Comment: Nothing there opens a link. You must have some other code that calls `window.open` or assigns to `window.location` using the information in the object.

Comment: The search widget has `newWindow:` option. So use `newWindow: true` when you create the widget.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. Your solution worked. I just had to download the file and make the change and upload it again. I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

if you `console.log(tipuesearch.pages[0].loc);` this gives you the link and you can use it in your HTML like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</body>
<script>
var tipuesearch = {"pages": [
{"title": "My title", "text": "Description of my title", "tags": "tag1, tag2", "loc": "http://www.example.com/"}
]};
function myFunction() {
    const link=tipuesearch.pages[0].loc;
    window.open(link, '_blank');
};
</script>
</html>
```